# After I install Buddyboss plugin my site crashes. I need the plugin so how can I use it?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

[this picture is shown whenever the site crashes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nvbp.png)

When I install the BuddyBoss plugin, this image is shown and my site crashes. How can I solve it? I need to use the plugin.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-5-9-and-buddypress-10-00-break-with-php-8-1/

Comment: I'm having the same issue while activating BuddyBoss Follow plugin. Did you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: No, I have not. Now it's not just for BuddyBoss It happens whenever I try to install any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Check you have the updated version of plugin. Also try to update WordPress.

**Step 2**

You can change the `memory_limit` by `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`

```
php_value memory_limit 2048M
```

Also try editing this value in **php.ini** not **Apache**.

If you can't update the WordPress or php then you can get the older version from the BuddyBoss plugin and get suitable version as per your WordPress.